backtesting with bt package in python: Why bt.Backtest, bt.run, returns a non changing weights and non changing equity progression?
I am backtesting a simple strategy buy/sell in Python. I pass the signals(1/-1) to bt.Strategy and data nd startegy to Backtest. But when I run I get a non-changing weights (all ae set at 1) and non changing progression and price.
strategy = bt.Strategy('Name',[bt.algos.WeighTarget(signal), bt.algos.Rebalance()])
btest = bt.Backtest(strategy,data_)[enter image description here][1]
res = bt.run(btest)
res.plot()
plt.show()

Here is the plot:
enter image description here
